# appengine sdk ImportError: No module named pwd

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, dev-appserver

When I use dev_appserver.py, it says ImportError: No module named pwd

My appengine sdk version is 1.9.17

Any idea?

Comment: Please edit the Q to show your full stack trace so we get some clues about where the error might be from -- don't go out of your way to make it as hard as possible for us to help you by withholding obviously crucial info!

Comment: +1 to @AlexMartelli, a more detailed info is necessary for a more detailed answer. 
As a quick thought, are you by any chance naming any of your own files _user.py_? This can cause conflicts with some App Engine libraries that already have that name, so if that's the case, please try changing it to, for example, _my_user.py_ and see if that works.

Comment: I was getting this same error just now. Haven't worked it out yet but there is some problem with importing packages names the same in different folders. perhaps. Unfortunately I changed server things since last looking at this part of the project. New Dev App Server but also upgraded to python 2.7.9

Comment: Use older SDK or tweak the current [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34311559/2818110).