# Google App Engine 'No module named pwd'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I was able to run my Google App Engine project (I am using Python Flask for developing a web app) well but when I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. The App Engine Project Became unresponsive on the local system whereas it is working well on the production environment. I also keep my project updated put my source code on github, so I deleted everything and again cloned a new repository of that from my github account. But When I am running the project it is giving me the following error, if anyone encountered this error before please help me out.

I use this command to run my project

```
$ dev_appserver.py src/
```

and get this error as output on the terminal

```
WARNING  2015-02-23 06:13:02,341 simple_search_stub.py:1115] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.practical-now-720.chitrank/search_indexes
INFO     2015-02-23 06:13:02,347 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:60268
INFO     2015-02-23 06:13:02,368 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-02-23 06:13:02,369 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2015-02-23 06:13:05,655 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chitrank/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/chitrank/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/chitrank/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-firstsubmit/uscore/src/run.py", line 5, in <module>
    import application
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-firstsubmit/uscore/src/application/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import urls
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-firstsubmit/uscore/src/application/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    from application import views
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-firstsubmit/uscore/src/application/views.py", line 49, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-firstsubmit/uscore/src/lib/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-firstsubmit/uscore/src/lib/requests/utils.py", line 19, in <module>
    from netrc import netrc, NetrcParseError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/netrc.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pwd
  File "/home/chitrank/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 898, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named pwd
INFO     2015-02-23 06:13:05,710 module.py:718] default: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

If anyone resolved this issue please help me out with removing the following problem.

Comment: Can you `import pwd` from general Python shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["ImportError: No module named pwd" but it exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819604/importerror-no-module-named-pwd-but-it-exists)

Comment: @Dmitry yes I am able to run ``import pwd`` from the general python Shell

Comment: @rnevius The above mentioned question does not able to solve my issue

Comment: See solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40475261/7049567 to switch to an older version of oauth2client.

Answer (score 8):

In `google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py` there is `_WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES` list, and adding `'pwd'` to it worked for me.

Google is actually running things in sandbox. As there is no issues in production environment, older GAE SDK's will support `pwd` import, but they are about to remove it.

Comment: I have added `pwd` to the array. but after the deploy the issue stays on.

Comment: @loretoparisi seems like Google removed the backward compatibility since it is deprecated.

Answer (score -2):

What version of requests do you use?

Can you illustrate as the following:

```
import requests
requests.version
'x.x.x'
$ dpkg -l | grep requests
```

On a side note: Probably the request version you are using is somehow old, I would advise you to upgrade if possible to 2.3.4 or the latest version and give it a try!.

You can have a look into these links:

[1] https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v2.2.1/requests/utils.py#L19

[2] https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1709